# Need help to fix the arrayoutofboundary exception for the below code

Tags: java, arrays, exception

How to fix arrayOutOfBoundException error message for the below code. This seem to be logically correct for me. But I'm not sure why I get this error. Need help on this

```
public class list  {

    public String reverseStr(String input){
        String reverString = input;
        int j=0;

        Character rev[] = new Character[reverString.length()-1];

        for(int i= reverString.length()-1;i> 0; --i){

            for(j = 0;j<= reverString.length()-1; ++j){
             rev[j] = reverString.charAt(i);
            }

        }
        String output = String.valueOf(rev[j]);
        return output;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        String reverse = "Ambika";
        list li = new list();
        System.out.println("The reverse of " + reverse + " is " + li.reverseStr(reverse));
    }
}
```

Comment: give FULL stackstrace.

Comment: You don't specify which line number.  This is not a puzzle web site.

Comment: @OldProgrammer `String output = String.valueOf(rev[j]);` That line

Comment: The nested for-loop would replace characters repeated without giving you reverse string. Check out http://stackoverflow.com/a/19106927/1433665

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are so many issues in your source,

1. You are defining an array with **one** length less than the acutual Sting size.

   `Character rev[] = new Character[reverString.length()-1];`

   It should have been,

   `Character rev[] = new Character[reverString.length()-1];`
2. Printing the value using the Index

   `String output = String.valueOf(rev[j]);`

   You can print using **for** loop

   `for (Character c : rev)`
      `System.out.print(c);`
3. You don't need two loops. **One loop** should be sufficient as below

   `int j = 0;`
   `for (int i = reverString.length() - 1; i >= 0; --i) {`
       `rev[j] = reverString.charAt(i);`
       `j++;`
   `}`
4. Finally you don't need a separate array to hold your result. You can hold the result in a `String` or `StringBuilder`.

Answer (score 1):

When inner for loop breaks, j will reach beyond the array bounds.
add `j--` before the line `String output = String.valueOf(rev[j]);`

On side note, you should make `rev` array big enough to hole whole string

```
  Character rev[] = new Character[reverString.length()];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(j = 0;j<= reverString.length()-1; ++j){
```

change to

```
 for(j = 0;j< reverString.length()-1; ++j){
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Untitled {

    public static String reverse( final String s )
    {
        return new StringBuilder(s).reverse().toString();            
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println( reverse( "Josh" ) );
    }
}
```

> hsoJ

Comment: This does not answer the question

Comment: @Tyler, Fair enough, but if it's being used in a production product, there is no reason to roll your own, simply because you're unaware of an elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

You initialized `rev` with size one less than the length of `reverString`

```
 Character rev[] = new Character[reverString.length()-1];
```

Change it to

```
Character rev[] = new Character[reverString.length()];
```

Actually, your whole idea of nested for-loop is a mess. You can simplify your program as follows;

```
public class list {

    public String reverseStr(String input) {
        String reverString = input;
        int j = 0;

        char rev[] = new char[reverString.length()];

        for (int i = reverString.length() - 1; i >= 0; --i) {

            rev[j++] = reverString.charAt(i);
        }

        String output = new String(rev);
        return output;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String reverse = "Ambika";
        list li = new list();
        System.out.println("The reverse of " + reverse + " is "
                + li.reverseStr(reverse));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things I noticed in your program. 
1. You do not need two loops to reverse the string, you can use one loop for traversing and increase the value of j to move.

```
int j=0;     
for(int i= reverString.length()-1;i>= 0; --i){           
             rev[j++] = reverString.charAt(i);
        }
```

1. Second if you noticed the above loop you will find that it is actually being invoked 6 time for value of i which is ( 5,4,3,2,1,0), so you need a array of size 6 which mean the size of rev should be 6 which is reverString.length()
   Please refer the code below.

   ```
   public class List  {
   public String reverseStr(String input){
       String reverString = input;
       int j=0;
       char rev[] = new char[reverString.length()-1];
       for(int i= reverString.length()-1;i>= 0; --i){           
            rev[j++] = reverString.charAt(i);
       }
       String output =String.valueOf(rev);
       return output;
   }
   public static void main(String args[]){
       String reverse = "Ambika";
       List li = new List();
       System.out.println("The reverse of " + reverse + " is " + li.reverseStr(reverse));
   }
   ```

   }